# Automating SQL schema changes on AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, flyway, rds, awsdeploy

What are the most common tooling and best practices to deploy SQL changes on AWS RDS databases?

Now we are considering a temporary flyway docker container running in our ECS, but it would be great if any of the managed AWS services had a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

Upto now, there aren't any manage services for sql migrations since its mostly unique for the database instance type(mysql, oracle & etc).

Generally if you go for code first approach, migrations are kept in the forms of changes, in a managed schema in code, while for database first approach, sql DML scripts are maintained.

Its also good a practice to automatically run these on continuous delivery tool, if any changes are available.

- List item

Comment: Some of our services uses code first migrations. But not all teams have realized the benefits of it yet, and still make use of StoredProcs and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You want your applications to always have an up-to-date database to ensure that all the objects they need are present. Therefore you should keep together what belongs together and **run your migrations on application or container startup**. This in turn means **packaging Flyway directly into your Docker image**.